# Unable to finde right cron job from nextcloud

Tags: docker, nextcloud, openmediavault

I want do shut down my nextcloud container but there is still a cron job running after i stop the container. This is because i run nextcloud with docker on my openmediavault server. The job comes oviously from openmediavault (salt or pillar) and i cant find the job on my server O_O

Somebody knows where i can find this job?

I tryed to change the settings on nextcloud and im searching width this command in my server:

```
grep -r "docker exec -u www-data nextcloud php /var/www/html/cron.php" /etc/ /srv/

or

crontab -e
```

but still found the file width this code in it:

```
# Lines below here are managed by Salt, do not edit
RANDOM_DELAY=15
*/5 * * * * docker exec -u www-data nextcloud php /var/www/html/cron.php
```

but where is the original i can edit?